# How to tell httpd to preserve the proxied error message?

Tags: proxy, tomcat, httpd, mod-proxy, custom-errors

I have an httpd server proxying the requests to 2 different tomcat servers.
One of my server handles the authentication and returns a specific http error code 521 when the user already have a running session.

My issue is httpd automatically maps this 521 error code to a 500 (internal server error) and then my client can not handle it properly.

I have tried to disable `ProxyErrorOverride`, to remove the `/error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var` but it does not changes anything.

How can I ask httpd to not change anything to the proxied message?

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
ProxyPass       /context1      http://127.0.0.1:8001/context1
ProxyPass       /context2      http://127.0.0.1:8002/context2
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyErrorOverride Off
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

- httpd 2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl
- tomcat 7.25
- windows 7 64-bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`521` isn't a valid HTTP response code, and Apache would be violating the HTTP specification by returning it.

Take a look at Apache's error log - it might actually be choking on the response code that it's getting from the backend and throwing an error to the client, not mapping the `5xx` code to `500`.

I'd strongly suggest against misusing HTTP response codes like this, but HAProxy or Varnish both have the ability to act as a 'dumb pipe', which might fit your needs.

Comment: ok, then if there is no way of doing that with httpd I'll reconsider the fact of using the http error code to advice the client of a specific error. Thanks